# Как правильно подключить цвет заднего фона?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Хочу, чтобы для каждого числа от 1 до 100 показывался свой цвет.

```php
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', '...', '...');
mysql_select_db('...');

$query = "SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

function getProperColor($color)
{
    if ($row['mark'] >= 90 && $row['mark'] < 101)
        return 'badge-darkgreen';
    elseif ($row['mark'] >= 50 && $row['mark'] < 75)
        return 'badge-yellow';
    elseif ($row['mark'] >= 75 && $row['mark'] < 90)
        return 'badge-succes';
    elseif ($row['mark'] >= 0 && $row['mark'] < 50)
        return 'badge-danger';
}

echo "<tbody>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['mode'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>
        <td><label class=\"badge " . getProperColor($result['color']) . "\">" . $row['mark'] . "</label></td>
        <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['teach'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: нам надо угадать, что у вас не получается?

Comment: для начала начните использовать переменную `$color` внутри вашей функции `getProperColor`. вместо `$row`.

Comment: Зачем городить огород на PHP, когда можно сразу посчитать требуемый `color` прямо на MySQL-сервере... более того - можно даже таблицу соответствия там создать.

Comment: Нужно не просто цвет, а именно те значения которые заданы внутри функции.

Comment: @Akina речь фактически про стилевое оформление. его на уровень пхп то выносить сомнительно, а пропихивать еще дальше в БД еще сомнительнее.

Comment: @Lexx918 чтобы ее использовать, туда надо что-то вразумительное передать сначала. Очевидно на вход там просится `$row['mark']`, а пока что имеем лишь нотис в логах.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пользуйтесь mysql драйвером для работы с субд. Пользуйтесь mysqli, либо pdo драйвером. MySQL уже реально устарел.

Answer (score 1):

Вам удобно с этими ифами разбираться? Нагляден ли этот код, прост для чтения и понимая? нет.
Что может быть удобно? соответствие оценка-цвет. Как проще всего задать соответствие - ключ-значение.

Что должна на вход функция получить? текущую оценку, очевидно, а получает что? нечто, даже не из `$row`.

```
function getProperColor($mark){

    $colors = [
         101 => 'dark-green'
         90  => 'success',
         75  => 'yellow',
         50  => 'danger',
       ];

    foreach($colors as $m => $color){
        if($mark < $m){
            $result = $color;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Возможно тут алгоритм не точен, и можно придумать различные вариации.  Но в лбом случае, подобные условия и соответствия явно не с помощью кучи if-ов надо описывать.

проверяем:

```
foreach([20,60, 80, 95] as $mark){
    $result[$mark] = getProperColor($mark);
}
print_r($result);
```

результат

```
Array (
    [20] => danger
    [60] => yellow
    [80] => success
    [95] => dark-green
)
```